# Saving data to Excel

Tags: c#

I have a windows application that upon submit creates an Excel file (if not already created) or appends to an Excel file. The file is being created each time but I also get a message asking if I want to copy over the file. I want to append to the file not rewrite the file. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Below is my code in my submit function:

```
string filePath = "C:\\Temp\\test.xlsx";

Excel.Application oApp;
Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
Excel.Workbook oBook;

oApp = new Excel.Application();
oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    using (File.CreateText(filePath))
  {
      oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "First Name"; oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Last Name"; oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Street Address"; oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "City"; oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "State";
      oSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Zip Code"; oSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "Phone"; oSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Email"; oSheet.Cells[1, 10] = "DOB"; oSheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Gender"; oSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "High School";
      oSheet.Cells[1, 13] = "Graduation Year"; oSheet.Cells[1, 14] = "Planned Term"; oSheet.Cells[1, 15] = "Intended Major";

      oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = txtFirstName.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 3] = txtLastName.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 4] = txtAddress.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 5] = txtCity.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 6] = txtState.Text;
      oSheet.Cells[2, 7] = txtZipCode.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 8] = txtPhone.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 9] = txtEmail.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 10] = dtpDOB.Value; oSheet.Cells[2, 11] = genderSet.ToString();
      oSheet.Cells[2, 12] = txtHighSchool.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 13] = txtGraduationYear.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 14] = txtTermofEnrollment.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 15] = outText.ToString();
  }
}
else
{
    using (File.AppendText(filePath))
    {
        oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = txtFirstName.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 3] = txtLastName.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 4] = txtAddress.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 5] = txtCity.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 6] = txtState.Text;
        oSheet.Cells[2, 7] = txtZipCode.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 8] = txtPhone.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 9] = txtEmail.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 10] = dtpDOB.Value; oSheet.Cells[2, 11] = genderSet.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[2, 12] = txtHighSchool.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 13] = txtGraduationYear.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 14] = txtTermofEnrollment.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 15] = outText.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: The `SaveAs` method will save changes to the workbook in a **different file**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.CreateText()` method opens a file to write UTF-8 encoded text and `File.AppendText()` method creates a `StreamWriter` to append UTF-8 encoded file to an existing file. An `Excel` file is different from a text file. You either need to use Excel Interop like you already are doing or use something like Open XML.

The code after modifying is:

```
string filePath = "C:\\Temp\\test.xlsx";

Excel.Application oApp;
Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
Excel.Workbook oBook;

oApp = new Excel.Application();

if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
    oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "First Name"; oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Last Name"; oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Street Address"; oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "City"; oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "State";
    oSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Zip Code"; oSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "Phone"; oSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Email"; oSheet.Cells[1, 10] = "DOB"; oSheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Gender"; oSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "High School";
    oSheet.Cells[1, 13] = "Graduation Year"; oSheet.Cells[1, 14] = "Planned Term"; oSheet.Cells[1, 15] = "Intended Major";

    oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = txtFirstName.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 3] = txtLastName.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 4] = txtAddress.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 5] = txtCity.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 6] = txtState.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[2, 7] = txtZipCode.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 8] = txtPhone.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 9] = txtEmail.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 10] = dtpDOB.Value; oSheet.Cells[2, 11] = genderSet.ToString();
    oSheet.Cells[2, 12] = txtHighSchool.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 13] = txtGraduationYear.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 14] = txtTermofEnrollment.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 15] = outText.ToString();
    oBook.SaveAs(filePath);
}
else
{
    oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Test\YourWorkbook.xlsx");

    oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = txtFirstName.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 3] = txtLastName.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 4] = txtAddress.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 5] = txtCity.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 6] = txtState.Text;
    oSheet.Cells[2, 7] = txtZipCode.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 8] = txtPhone.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 9] = txtEmail.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 10] = dtpDOB.Value; oSheet.Cells[2, 11] = genderSet.ToString();
    oSheet.Cells[2, 12] = txtHighSchool.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 13] = txtGraduationYear.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 14] = txtTermofEnrollment.Text; oSheet.Cells[2, 15] = outText.ToString();
    oBook.Save();
}

oBook.Close();
oApp.Quit();
oSheet = null;
oBook = null;
oApp = null;
```

Comment: Thank you. I made the modifications above and the file is not being recreated but the new data is not being appended. It is writing over any data currently in the excel file. Am I missing a step?

Comment: I figured out the step I was missing. I needed to increment the rowCount and modify the cells:

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new Excel worksheet every time you call the function. If you want to append data to your existing excel file, you have to first open it, append the data you need and then call the `save` function.

You can open the existing one like this

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
```

Now you can modify its data and when you're done, save and close.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the step I was missing. I needed to increment the rowCount and modify the cells as such. It appears to working as needed:

```
else
            {
                oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\\Temp\\test.xlsx");
                oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = oSheet.UsedRange;

                int rowCount = range.Rows.Count + 1;



                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2] = txtFirstName.Text; 
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 3] = txtLastName.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 4] = txtAddress.Text; 
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 5] = txtCity.Text; 
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 6] = txtState.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 7] = txtZipCode.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 8] = txtPhone.Text; 
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 9] = txtEmail.Text; 
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 10] = dtpDOB.Value; 
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 11] = genderSet.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 12] = txtHighSchool.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 13] = txtGraduationYear.Text;
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 14] = txtTermofEnrollment.Text; 
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, 15] = outText.ToString();
                oBook.Save();
            }
```